# Where can I find the Telegram bot API TOKEN?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have recently signed up for using telegram bot API but when I look into every example, it says to include API TOKEN of our own but have not mentioned how to get the token.

> When I go to Telegram site , all it shows me are some api id , hash and a RSA key pair .

How do I generate a telegram API **Token** or how and where to get one ?

Answer (score 8):

You can refer to [this FAQ](http://telegra.ph/Awesome-Telegram-Bot-11-11), bot token can obtain from [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather).

> Use the `/newbot` command to create a new bot. The Bot Father will ask you for a name and username, then generate an authorization token for your new bot.